# TYPO3 shariff extension language detection

Tags: typo3, multilingual, sharing, typo3-extensions

I use TYPO3 6.2 and the Extension shariff. The default language of this extension is english, but the buttons are always translated to german. My website is multilingual (en, de). The Buttons are included via backend for both languages. How could I define the language per content element "Shariff Social Icons"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clarify your question a bit. What do you mean by "language per record"?

The language is detected automatically from the language configured for the current page. So it automatically adjusts if the language is changed.

See also: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/rx_shariff/Installation/Index.html#fluid-view-helper

If you need to set a language manually you can do that via the `data-lang` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed my question. In the ShariffViewHelper.php file $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_isocode isn't set. I think that this is maybe my fault. The Extension requires typo3 version 6.2.9 and my version is 6.2.0. But I need to make it work without any updates... How could I do this with the Fluid view helper, when I need to include "Shariff Social Icons" as Content Element?

Comment: You can simply override the template for the index action.

Comment: `tt_content.list.20.rxshariff_shariff.view.templateRootPaths.0 = yourpath/`

Answer (score 0):

You can add override for Shariff Index.html by copying **typo3conf/ext/rx_shariff/Resources/Private/Templates/Shariff/Index.html** to **typo3conf/ext/YourExtension/Resources/Private/Templates/Shariff/Index.html** (your extension / override template path)

And add following override to setup typo-script:

```
plugin.tx_rxshariff.view {
    templateRootPaths{
        2 = EXT:YourExtension/Resources/Private/Templates/
    }
}
```

Add your modification to your overridden file (*typo3conf/ext/YourExtension/Resources/Private/Templates/Shariff/Index.html*).